# Jquery object list get list where id greater than given id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var sa=[{id:1,name:'ABC'},{id:2,name:'BCD'},{id:3,name:'PLM'},{id:4,name:'ERV'},{id:5,name:'SRT'},{id:6,name:'MNO'},{id:7,name:'XYZ'}]
```

sa is my object list i want list of id greater than 5.that means i need like this

```
var result=[{id:6,name:'MNO'},{id:7,name:'XYZ'}]
```

Comment: what else did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take several appraches to this problem:

1. Do a linear/binary search by writing your own custom function.
2. Or simply use this:

   var result = $.map(sa, function(element, index) {
           if (element.id  > 5) {
               return element;
           }
       });

Comment: The `map()` function likely isn't the most appropriate to handle this scenario, as it's purpose is really to convert/transform items within an array whereas the `filter()` method will simply select and return a subset of items based on a condition, which is what the question is asking. If you wanted to transform the data, then you could use `map()` but as seen by the comment in my answer, the `filter()` method can be used to update items as well as filter them out.

Comment: Actually you are correct @RionWilliams. I just suggested one of the approaches, but yours is better if in-place filtering is required. In case we need to create another list after filtering, I guess my approach is better.

Comment: The `filter()` function doesn't filter / reduce the list in-place. It creates and returns a separate filtered array. The `map()` function is more appropriate if you needed to perform a conversion on all of the elements within the collection (and return the transformed results).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the available [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function to handle this:

```
var results = sa.filter(function(item) {
    return item.id > 5;
});
```

**Example**

```js
// Your original array
var sa=[{id:1,name:'ABC'},{id:2,name:'BCD'},{id:3,name:'PLM'},{id:4,name:'ERV'},{id:5,name:'SRT'},{id:6,name:'MNO'},{id:7,name:'XYZ'}]
// Store the results in your filtered array
var results = sa.filter(function(item){
     return item.id > 5;
});
// Log them to the console
console.log(results);
```

Comment: thanks and i want to update name by 'NA'.how it possible?[{id:6,name:'NA'},{id:7,name:'NA'}] in sa object?

Comment: If you wanted to update the name as well, you could simply set the value within the body of the filter function (i.e. `function(item){ item.name = 'NA'; return item.id > 5; }`.